# How to place textual labels directly on a Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a question regarding the Google JavaScript Map API.

When searching for places on maps.google.com (i.e. Starbucks), Google Maps adds a marker with the text Starbucks next to it:

[image]

Is it possible to do this same behavior with custom markers and text? I was able to see how to pass a [custom image for the marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#icons), but I was unable to find how to add the label text. The example that I found in the API was using the Info window, but that can get kind of bulky for me.

Comment: This feature is pretty well documented in the API docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/custom-markers

Comment: I am not asking about the marker.  I am asking about the label text next to the marker.

Comment: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/docs/examples.html

Comment: Meta discussion [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253662).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[MarkerWithLabel](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/docs/reference.html)** is a part of the [Google Maps Utility Library](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/) that extends the Google Maps JavaScript API V3 `google.maps.Marker` class, allowing you to define markers with associated labels.

As you would expect, if the marker is draggable, so too will be the label. In addition, a marker with a label responds to all mouse events in the same manner as a regular marker. It also fires mouse events and "property changed" events just as a regular marker would.

### Creating a Basic Marker

The example below shows how to use MarkerWithLabel to create a marker that has a label centered beneath it in a small box. The label can be styled most easily by defining a CSS class with the desired properties for the label DIV. In this example the class is called "labels" and this name is passed in the labelClass parameter to MarkerWithLabel. Additional styling information can be passed in the labelStyle parameter. The text of the label is passed in labelContent. Other parameters that can be passed to MarkerWithLabel are identical to those that can be passed to google.maps.Marker.

```
 <style type="text/css">
   .labels {
     color: red;
     background-color: white;
     font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
     font-size: 10px;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: center;
     width: 40px;     
     border: 2px solid black;
     white-space: nowrap;
   }
 </style>

     var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47805, -123.84716);
     var homeLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47805, -123.84716);

     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
       zoom: 12,
       center: latLng,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     });

     var marker1 = new MarkerWithLabel({
       position: homeLatLng,
       draggable: true,
       raiseOnDrag: true,
       map: map,
       labelContent: "$425K",
       labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
       labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
       labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}
     });

     var iw1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
       content: "Home For Sale"
     });
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, "click", function (e) { iw1.open(map, this); });
```

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/docs/reference.html